# converting SMILES (or .mol2) to SMARTS

Tags: software, cheminformatics

The conversion between different chemical structure formats, e.g. from .mol2 to .xyz, by [openbabel](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Main_Page) may tied to conditions to be met.  One example of such a filter is to allow such a conversion only for data sharing a certain scaffold, e.g.

```
obabel -imol2 AHECAS.mol2 -oxyz AHECAS.xyz -s "c1ccccc1-[#16](=[#8])-[#6]-c2ccccc2"
```

So the program allows SMARTS as constraining input parameter.  In difference to SMILES, (apparently, based on `babel -L formats`) openbabel however does not offer a conversion of any format into SMARTS and my source to generate them is the on-line [PubChem Sketcher](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/edit2/index.html).

Question:  Aiming to generate SMARTS locally (offline), I know Marvin by ChemAxon may export a structure into SMARTS.  However, is there a portable alternative (with lesser footprint than a complete new GUI sketcher), preferentially allowing a conversion in a pattern like `SMILES2SMARTS` (or `mol2toSMARTS`) from the terminal / by a script?

Comment: Similar thread on Openbabel forum: [Conversion of SMILES to SMARTS String](http://forums.openbabel.org/Conversion-of-SMILES-to-SMARTS-String-td4657615.html)

Comment: Please note that `babel` is the old interface. The recommend `obabel`instead now. See https://openbabel.org/docs/dev/Command-line_tools/babel.html#babel-vs-obabel

Answer (score 3):

The thread indicated in the comment by @andselisk dates back to July 2014. It may be condensed to

> "A substructure querying with `openbabel` requires *a good* SMARTS string. In case you don't have one, often *a good* SMILES string may be used instead of a SMARTS string, too."

A check for a rather simple molecular structure of (benzylsulfinyl)benzene

[image]

there is more than one way to describe it in either form of a SMARTS, or a SMILES string.  Consequently, the strings *per se* sometimes differ from each other.  Consequently, recognizing the relevant entries in the collection of `.mol2` with `openbabel` sometimes *failed*.

Below I summarize (status: 2019-May-15) a few experiences: the string offered by the software, its type, and source; eventually, if it worked (i.e., entries retrieved), or not (i.e., entries not retrieved) in a small test set of 419 model data and 7 relevant hits.

```
|-------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+--------|
| entry                               | type   | source             | status |
|-------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+--------|
| c1ccccc1-[#6]-[#16](-c2ccccc2)=[#8] | SMARTS | pubChemSketcher    | works  |
| C1=CC=CC=C1C[S](C2=CC=CC=C2)=O      | SMILES | pubChemSketcher    | fails  |
|-------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+--------|
| O=S(Cc1ccccc1)c2ccccc2              | SMILES | ACD ChemSketch     | works  |
|-------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+--------|
| C1=CC=C(C=C1)CS(C(C=CC1)=CC=1)=O    | SMILES | ChemDoodle         | fails  |
|-------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+--------|
| O=S(C1=CC=CC=C1)CC2=CC=CC=C2        | SMILES | ChemDraw Pro12     | fails  |
|-------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+--------|
| O=S(CC1=CC=CC=C1)C1=CC=CC=C1        | SMILES | Marvin JS          | fails  |
|-------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+--------|
| O=S(Cc1ccccc1)c2ccccc2              | SMILES | Peter Ertl JSME    | works  |
|-------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+--------|
| c1cccc(c1)CS(=O)c1ccccc1            | SMILES | openbabel, default | works  |
| c1ccc(cc1)CS(=O)c1ccccc1            | SMILES | dito, universal    | works  |
| c1ccc(cc1)CS(=O)c1ccccc1            | SMILES | dito, Inchified    | works  |
| O=S(c1ccccc1)Cc1ccccc1              | SMILES | dito, canonical    | works  |
|-------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+--------|

PubChem Sketcher: version 2.4, https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/edit2/index.html
ACD ChemSketch:   Freeeware version 2015
ChemDoodle:       version 8.1.0, 2019 and webcomponents,
                  https://web.chemdoodle.com/demos/sketcher/
ChemDraw:         version 12 Pro, (then) CambridgeSoft, 2009
Marvin JS:        ChemAxon, v19.11.0, on-line test at
                  https://marvinjs-demo.chemaxon.com/latest/
                  Its SMARTS (very differently written) equally failed:
                  O=S([#6]-[#6]-1=[#6]-[#6]=[#6]-[#6]=[#6]-1)[#6]-1=[#6]-[#6]=[#6]-[#6]=[#6]-1
Peter Ertl JSME:  https://peter-ertl.com/jsme/JSME_2017-02-26/
```

**Addition:**
The approach mentioned in the question basically calls `obabel` (or `òpenbabel`) as an iteration *per file*.  Especially if the data set is accessed more than once to identify different structures, and / or consists of multiple thousand models, this may be tediously slow.  Instead, it is worth to "bundle" the individual information

```
obabel *.mol2 mymols.sdf --unique
```

creating a container like a multi-model `.mol2` (this even works with `.xyz` files as input).  The `.sdf` may be indexed

```
obabel mymols.sdf -ofs
```

by fingerprints (cf. chapter 5 of the manual).  Now, *very quickly* the names of the files about a structure matching the query substructure are identified, e.g.

```
obabel mymols.fs -ifs -s"O=S(c1ccccc1)Cc1ccccc1" results.smi -xt
```

and stored in `results.smi`.  Consequently, any further work may focus on them.

Comment: "If you deploy either a SMARTS, or a SMILES string on Linux' bash" If you enclose the string in `''` to make it literal, you do not have to escape anything.